# Google API URL return no results

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-search-api

I need a PHP Google search function, so I tried many function I found in Google, but almost all have the same problem which is they take results directly from Google main URL not from the API URL, which lead after a while to an error because Google detect the visits are from a PHP server and reject any further requests.

So I made my Google search function takes results from Google API URL, and that worked perfectly as you see here [#API_URL](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=2.0&q=maleficent%202014%20site:www.anakbnet.com/video/file.php?f=) until I needed to reduce the results buy adding **intitle:** before the searched keyword, and now the API URL return no result at all as you see here [#API_URL](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=2.0&q=intitle:maleficent%202014%20site:www.anakbnet.com/video/file.php?f=).

My question is simple, how do I get results in the Google API URL using this query **intitle:maleficent+2014+site:www.anakbnet.com/video/file.php?f=** so that I can take Results from it using PHP?

Comment: Have you firstly signed up to Google and then registered to use their apis? There is a google search api you can use - you need an api key and need to read their documentation - but you should be able to seamlessly integrate that search functionality into your site.
You can find their api console https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: That's way complected for me, I just know how to use the API URL like the one in the question!

Answer (score 1):

The data you get back from your 'Google API' call is json encoded data so you should try something like the following:-

```
    /* define a constant for ease */
    define('BR','<br />');


    $data='{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.anakbnet.com/video/file.php?f\u003d1452","url":"http://www.anakbnet.com/video/file.php%3Ff%3D1452","visibleUrl":"www.anakbnet.com","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:9-JgVUvjnGYJ:www.anakbnet.com","title":"مشاهدة فيلم Alexander and the Terrible اون لاين مباشرة بدون تحميل \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e","titleNoFormatting":"مشاهدة فيلم Alexander and the Terrible اون لاين مباشرة بدون تحميل ...","content":"29 كانون الثاني (يناير) 2015 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e مشاهدة فيلم \u003cb\u003eMaleficent 2014\u003c/b\u003e DVD HD مترجم اون لاين مباشرة بدون تحميل اكشن ,مغامرة \n,عائلي .. مشاهدة افلام اجنبية مترجمة اونلاين كاملة. (مشاهدة: 491,605 )."}],"cursor":{"resultCount":"1","pages":[{"start":"0","label":1}],
     "estimatedResultCount":"1",
     "currentPageIndex":0,
     "moreResultsUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?oe\u003dutf8\u0026ie\u003dutf8\u0026source\u003duds\u0026start\u003d0\u0026hl\u003den-GB\u0026q\u003dmaleficent+2014+site:www.anakbnet.com/video/file.php?f%3D",
     "searchResultTime":"0.09"}}, 
     "responseDetails": null, 
     "responseStatus": 200}';



   $json=json_decode( $data, true );
   $res=(object)$json['responseData']['results'][0];

   /* two items extracted from data - use same methodology to get other items */
   echo $res->unescapedUrl;
   echo $res->cacheUrl;



    echo '<pre>';
    foreach( $json as $key => $param ){
        echo $key.BR;
        if( is_array( $param )) $param=(object)$param;  
        print_r( $param );
    }
    echo '</pre>';
```

Hopefully from that you can find what you want?!